# javascript settimeout different result on firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript

i have just test a settimeout and setInterval method on firefox and chrome.
but i found some different look on the result.
so hope somebody can explain to me the logic. 
because now i getting some bug and i suspect on it.

```
function test() {
    var i = 0;
    setTimeout(function () {
        i = 10;
    }, 4);
    setInterval(function () {
        i++;
    }, 4);
    alert("alert");
    alert(i);
}
test();
```

above is a simple js code. the result on firefox usually is 11, but something is 0.
in chrome, the result always is 0;
so what cause the result so different ? 
any idea ?

Comment: The reason why chrome is getting 0 is because it's getting to the alert before 4milliseconds has passed. Firefox on the other hand is taking anywhere from 4-7 milliseconds.

Comment: I get 0 on both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Apparently, Firefox lets each timer fire once during the first `alert()`.  I have no idea why.  If you remove the first `alert()`, then you get `0` in Firefox, just like in Chrome.

Comment: I used FF (40.0.3) and Chrome on Mac and output is consistently 0 in both

Comment: using alert and family for debugging asynchronous code is a recipe for inconsistency

Comment: it takes time for code to run,  you can't rely that both browsers will take the exact same time to run it. Chrome clearly managed to alert before 4milliseconds, while firefox didn't

Comment: Both 'setTimeout()' and 'setInterval()' will run asynchronously and queued up so the result should always be 0.

Comment: @prasun - duh, you would think it should be 0, but it isn't in Firefox.  It shows 11 for me.  Try this in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cpsjqcbj/

Comment: @jfriend00 interesting which version of FF you tried and on which OS?

Comment: @jfriend00 for me it (ff 41.0.2) shows 0 and I would qualify everything else as a bug.

Comment: @prasun - Firefox 41.0.2 on Windows 10 shows 11.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have win10, but, I will try that tomorrow on my colleagues' machines. But, I will agree with @zerkms

Comment: @zerkms - I get 11 on Firefox 41.0.2 on Windows 10.  So, Firefox is apparently inconsistent on this (I'm assuming a platform variation).

Comment: If someone files a bug - please put a link here

Comment: What is this code being used for? Also, you may have more clearer results if you use console.log instead of alert since it, at least intuitively, should be able to process the data more quickly. It certainly will output more quickly.

Comment: @SkyBoydston "more quickly" is not acceptable for a single threaded language.

Comment: I get the same result as @jfriend00 (11). It seems it has to do something with the `alert()` (or the time needed to open/close it), because if I replace them with `console.log()`, the result is always 0.

Comment: For completeness, both IE 11 and Edge show `0`.  So, Firefox seems to be the outlier here.   And, it isn't just the latest version of Firefox that exhibits this as I saw it on two prior versions too.

Comment: And, both Firefox 40.0.2 and 41.0.2 on Windows 8 shows `12`.

Comment: ok, thank you guys sharing. i think i don depend on it better.